# Help with a function in a widget

Tags: plugins, functions

I'm new to custom widgets and functions, and need a bit of help understanding how to achieve something.

On my bookstore site I need to display links to books on external site using their ISBN numbers.  I'm already getting their Google Books preview with a function in my theme's functions.php, but now I want to put other links in a sidebar widget.  I've managed to make a new blank widget and get it to show up.  This is the code I've tried to get the ISBN from the post meta data (meta key is isbn_metadata), but I'm not getting it right.

```
function get_kalahari_affiliate_link() {
$isbn_metadata = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), '_isbn' ); 
return (        
    'http://etrader.kalahari.net/referral.asp?linkid=5&partnerid=5710&ISBN=' . 
    $isbn_metadata 
);
}
echo get_kalahari_affiliate_link( get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), '_isbn' ) );
```

I get a link to appear, but it's:

```
http://etrader.kalahari.net/referral.asp?linkid=5&partnerid=5710&ISBN=Array
```

The second problem is that it only appears on my primary sidebar, and not in any of the custom "widget areas" (http://docs.woothemes.com/documentation/plugins/woosidebars/) which might mean the plugin is not properly registered for those?

I'd appreciate some help!

Here is the update - the widget is stolen from a widget template tutorial here http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/how-to-create-wordpress-widgets/
Skip down to  "Widget code goes here".

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: Random Post Widget
Plugin URI: http://jamesbruce.me/
Description: Random Post Widget grabs a random post and the associated thumbnail to display on your sidebar
Author: James Bruce
Version: 1
Author URI: http://jamesbruce.me/
*/


class RandomPostWidget extends WP_Widget
{
  function RandomPostWidget()
  {
    $widget_ops = array('classname' => 'RandomPostWidget', 'description' => 'Displays a random post with thumbnail' );
    $this->WP_Widget('RandomPostWidget', 'Random Post and Thumbnail', $widget_ops);
  }

  function form($instance)
  {
    $instance = wp_parse_args( (array) $instance, array( 'title' => '' ) );
    $title = $instance['title'];
?>
  <p><label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('title'); ?>">Title: <input class="widefat" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('title'); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('title'); ?>" type="text" value="<?php echo attribute_escape($title); ?>" /></label></p>
<?php
  }

  function update($new_instance, $old_instance)
  {
$instance = $old_instance;
$instance['title'] = $new_instance['title'];
return $instance;
  }

  function widget($args, $instance)
  {
    extract($args, EXTR_SKIP);

echo $before_widget;
$title = empty($instance['title']) ? ' ' : apply_filters('widget_title', $instance['title']);

if (!empty($title))
  echo $before_title . $title . $after_title;;



// WIDGET CODE GOES HERE

  echo "<h1>This is my new widget!</h1>";


function get_kalahari_affiliate_link() {
    $isbn_metadata = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'isbn_metadata' ); 
return (        
    'http://etrader.kalahari.net/referral.asp?linkid=5&partnerid=5710&ISBN=' . 
    $isbn_metadata 
);
}
echo get_kalahari_affiliate_link( get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'isbn_metadata' ) );

echo $after_widget;
  }

}
add_action( 'widgets_init', create_function('', 'return     register_widget("RandomPostWidget");') );?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, if meta key is `isbn_metadata` is the `meta_key` you should specify this meta key instead of `_isbn`.

Second, `get_post_meta` return an array unless you set the third parameter to true. So, you can do this:

```
function get_kalahari_affiliate_link() {
    $isbn_metadata = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'isbn_metadata', true );
    if( ! empty( $isbn_metadata ) ) {
        $link = 'http://etrader.kalahari.net/referral.asp?linkid=5&partnerid=5710&ISBN=' . $isbn_metadata;
    } else {
         //Empty string or you can set any other value for control
         $link = '';
    }
    return $link;
}
```

Note: You are using `get_the_ID()` , I assume you are executing the function inside the loop as required by `get_the_ID()`.

About the widget areas problem, as you are using a third party software, you should ask to the developer.

Comment: Thanks cybmeta. I tried this and now it's blank!  Also, as a beginner, I'm not sure if it's inside the loop or not?  Sorry, new to this.

Comment: Show us the full code you are using and where you are calling this function. If you get a blank page it is not because the code I posted, 100% sure. Also, [The loop](http://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop).

Comment: OK, I'm not sure where to paste the code - should I edit the original question?

Comment: Yes, edit the question.

Comment: OK, hope that helps.

Comment: I've just copied and pasted your code and I don't get any error. The only problem is that you can't use `get_the_ID` because you are outside The Loop. Define the post ID you want to display in another way.